# Doc file download not working in rails 7 in windows. How to fix?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to download a custom doc file in rails 7. It is working in all machines, but not working in windows.

I have created a button and a function named downloadDoc, after click on the button this function runs and downloads doc file. In windows the content of the file is comming blank, but in other machine it is comming with content.

```
  downloadDoc() {
    // Cif Inputs
    var labelsCont = document.getElementsByClassName("cif_form_export_filed_labels")
    var valuesCont = document.getElementsByClassName("cif_form_export_filed_values")
    var labels = []
    var values = []
    var allFields = ""

    Object.values(labelsCont).map(el => labels.push(el.value || ""))
    Object.values(valuesCont).map(el => values.push(el.value || ""))

    labels.map((l, i) => {
      allFields += `<h4>${l}  -  ${values[i]}</h4>`
    })


    // map photos
    var allPhotos = ""
    const a = document.getElementsByClassName('cif_photos')
    var photos = []
    Object.values(a).map(el => {
      photos.push(JSON.parse(el.value));
    })

    const groupedMap = photos.reduce(
      (aa, e) => aa.set(e.photo_type, [...aa.get(e.photo_type) || [], e]),
      new Map()
    );

    groupedMap.forEach((v, k) => {
      allPhotos += `<h4>${k}</h4>`
      v.map(img => {
        allPhotos += `<h5>${img.location}</h5>`
        allPhotos += `<img src=${img.url} width=200px height=200px > `
      })
    })


    // download process
    var preHtml = "<html xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office' xmlns:w='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'><head><meta charset='utf-8'><title>Export HTML To Doc</title></head><body>";
    var postHtml = "</body></html>";
    var html = preHtml + postHtml + "<h2>CIF Fields</h2>" + allFields + "<h2>CIF Photos</h2>" + allPhotos + "<h2>Summary</h2>";

    var blob = new Blob(['\ufeff', html], {
      type: 'application/msword'
    });

    var url = 'data:application/vnd.ms-word;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(html);
    var filename = 'document.docx';
    var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

    if (navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
      navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, filename);
    } else {
      downloadLink.href = url;
      downloadLink.download = filename;
      downloadLink.click();
    }


  }
```

I have tried many gems, but not able to add photos in it. Only text is comming.

Comment: have you tried opening the docs on windows that were generated on other systems?

Comment: yes, not working.

Comment: well, if documents that were generated on other systems don't open on windows then it's a problem with the way you open them on windows, not with the way they are generated